# iOS app permissions to access the camera

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, permissions, camera

I'm developing a iOS app from phonegap and I seem to have issues with the camera permissions:

On 2 of my test devices (ipad mini, and ipad2) the permissions are fine.
On 2 of my test devices (iphone 5, iphone 6s) the permissions don't work properly. When I go to the settings app and check the permissions for my app on the iPads it shows Camera as one item, but it doesn't on the 2 test iphones.
I cannot imagine this is a problem between the device families but maybe it is? Could someone give a hint for what's going wrong?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the iOS version, are they same for all the devices

Comment: ipad mini runs ios10.1.1
ipad 2 runs ios 9.3.5
iphone 6s runs ios 10.1.1
so this cannot be the issue @Rajat